# Rearranging terms in a summation and product

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the countable set of finitely-supported multi-indices, i.e. $$\mathcal{F} = \{\nu\in\mathbb{N}_0^{\mathbb{N}}:\nu_1+\nu_2+\ldots<\infty\}.$$
Let $(\rho_j)_{j\geq 1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. Then, we have
$$
\sum_{\nu\in\mathcal{F}}\prod_{j\geq 1}\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^{r}{\nu_j\choose \ell}\rho^\ell_j\right)^q = \prod_{j\geq 1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^{r}{n\choose \ell}\rho^\ell_j\right)^q,$$
with the convention that
$${n\choose m}=0\quad\text{if}\quad m>n.$$
It looks like it is doing some factorisation, but I can't see it cearly even if I write the sum explicitly. May I know what exactly it is doing with this series?

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$f(n,j):=\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^{r}{n\choose \ell}\rho^\ell_j\right)^q>0.$$
Generally,
$$
\sum_{\nu\in\mathcal{F}}\prod_{j\geq 1}f(\nu_j,j)<\prod_{j\geq 1}\sum_{n\geq 0}f(n,j)$$
because when you develop the RHS, you get the sum of finite products of the LHS but also the sum of infinite products, which may be $>0.$